# MobileFirst [GatewayChallengeHandler]: Android application crashes while trying to access server resource

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to Android platform.

I started writing MobileFirstPlatform 8 app for Android, where I need to authenticate the app against a reverse proxy. I started following the blog https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/datapower-integration/

While executing the Android app, the android app crashes just after MFP server returns back with "403 Forbidden", when the application tries to reach "/mfp/api/adapters/ResourceAdapter/balance".

I checked the behavior of the DataPower Cordova app and found it to be working correctly.

1. After the cordova app requests "/mfp/api/adapters/ResourceAdapter/balance"
2. MFP server issues 403 Forbidden.
3. Cordova app requests for "/mfp/api/preauth/v1/preauthorize
4. MFP server returns "401 Unauthorize" with correct challenges in json payload.

Whereas, in the Android app, the app crashes after step 2 above. So it never gets to the point of issuing request (step 3).

The stack trace of the crash:

```
09-08 02:13:28.376 3914-3945/com.sample.datapowerandroid E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler: Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException in Logger.java:444 :: Uncaught Exception
                                                                                                             java.lang.Error: Multiple values for 'WWW-Authenticate' header were detected
                                                                                                                 at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.getAuthorizationScope(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:1328)
                                                                                                                 at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.getAuthorizationScope(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:365)
                                                                                                                 at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResourceRequest.handleOnSuccess(WLResourceRequest.java:687)
                                                                                                                 at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResourceRequest.access$100(WLResourceRequest.java:65)
                                                                                                                 at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResourceRequest$1.onResponse(WLResourceRequest.java:596)
                                                                                                                 at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:177)
                                                                                                                 at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
                                                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

AND

```
09-08 02:13:28.378 3914-4041/com.sample.datapowerandroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
                                                                       Process: com.sample.datapowerandroid, PID: 3914
                                                                       java.lang.Error: Multiple values for 'WWW-Authenticate' header were detected
                                                                           at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.getAuthorizationScope(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:1328)
                                                                           at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.getAuthorizationScope(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:365)
                                                                           at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResourceRequest.handleOnSuccess(WLResourceRequest.java:687)
                                                                           at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResourceRequest.access$100(WLResourceRequest.java:65)
                                                                           at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResourceRequest$1.onResponse(WLResourceRequest.java:596)
                                                                           at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:177)
                                                                           at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Thanks/regards
Pranab

EDIT 1:
Reverse Proxy used: IBM Security Access Manager.
The proxy currently is configured to let the traffic flow seamlessly between the app and the MFP server.

The app is only changed to submit the form response to the proxy at the correct URL. The only other change to the default app is the minSdkVersion that I have changed to 15 (Not sure if that is relevant).

The app is pointing to the reverse proxy and not MFP. But after your query, I did test it against the MFP server directly. When pointing directly to the MFP server without ISAM in between, I see a different behavior. Instead of app crash, the app is throwing the message "Missing challenge handler for security check".

I have reconfirmed the resource settings on the MFP server and they are configured to call LtpaBasedSSO security check and app is configured to handler the challenge from MFP. If I check the data between MFP server and app (via WireShark) I can see the correct security check being invoked. But for some reason, the Android app either barfs (when ISAM is in between) or throws the error message.

EDIT 2:

```
public void submitLogin(String userName, String password){
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("UserName", userName);
    params.put("Password", password);
    submitLoginForm("../../../../../../../pkmslogin.form", params, null, 0, "post");
}
```

EDIT 3:
After reading your comment, I started looking at the app code once again and realized that ISAMs form is not getting thrown at the app at all. I modified the ISAM configuration to hide the server resource behind the ISAM (earlier it was short-circuited to pass through).

1. Now, when the app requests the server resource (/balance), ISAM throws the login form.
2. The app goes ahead and does what it needs to do with MFP server (auth, getting token etc.) and then requests for server resource once again.
3. The server resource, being behind ISAM (which is not yet authenticated), throws login form, again.
4. canHandleChallenge() correctly identifies the page and returns true, but the challenge handler does not get kicked in.

NOTE: ISAMs login form comes with HTTP status of 200 (if it matters).

5. Since the challenge handler does not get kicked in, app goes ahead and makes the same request again (and again -> infinite loop).

After changing the ISAMs configuration, I tested the DataPower for Cordova app as well, and it too went into infinite loop.

```
@Override
public boolean canHandleResponse(WLResponse wlResponse) {
    Log.d(TAG,"canHandleResponse");

    if (wlResponse == null
            || wlResponse.getResponseText() == null ||
            !wlResponse.getResponseText().contains("/pkmslogin.form")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Wrong Challenge");
        return false;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Right Challenge");
    return true;
}
```

EDIT 4:
After you posted your question, I went ahead and put all the MFP URLs behind the gateway. I tested the configuration with the Cordova app and it is working correctly.

The Datapower Android app, now, shows the login form correctly. After putting the login creds and ISAM authenticating the user, gets a 302 redirect correctly. App tries to access the resource once again, which results in a 403 Forbidden (similar to Cordova app) and then the app crashes.

The stack trace is

```
09-12 01:31:24.732 26815-26923/com.sample.datapowerandroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
                                                                         Process: com.sample.datapowerandroid, PID: 26815
                                                                         java.lang.Error: Multiple values for 'WWW-Authenticate' header were detected
                                                                             at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.getAuthorizationScope(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:1328)
                                                                             at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.getAuthorizationScope(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:365)
                                                                             at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResourceRequest.handleOnSuccess(WLResourceRequest.java:687)
                                                                             at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResourceRequest.access$100(WLResourceRequest.java:65)
                                                                             at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResourceRequest$1.onResponse(WLResourceRequest.java:596)
                                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:177)
                                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

AND

```
09-12 01:31:24.732 26815-26846/com.sample.datapowerandroid E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler: Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException in Logger.java:444 :: Uncaught Exception
                                                                                                               java.lang.Error: Multiple values for 'WWW-Authenticate' header were detected
                                                                                                                   at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.getAuthorizationScope(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:1328)
                                                                                                                   at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.getAuthorizationScope(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:365)
                                                                                                                   at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResourceRequest.handleOnSuccess(WLResourceRequest.java:687)
                                                                                                                   at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResourceRequest.access$100(WLResourceRequest.java:65)
                                                                                                                   at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResourceRequest$1.onResponse(WLResourceRequest.java:596)
                                                                                                                   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:177)
                                                                                                                   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
                                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

EDIT 5

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
content-length: 0
date: Mon, 12 Sep 2016 04:51:56 GMT
p3p: CP="NON CUR OTPi OUR NOR UNI"
www-authenticate: Bearer error="insufficient_scope"
www-authenticate: scope="accessRestricted"
x-powered-by: Servlet/3.1
```

Comment: Let's try to add more data to the question. What kind of reverse proxy? What kind of authentication is the proxy doing? The the android app 100% the same as the sample or did you modify? Is the app pointing to the proxy or to mfp? Is the app working without the proxy?

Comment: I did not mean to you to put all this information in the comments. I meant that you should update your question

Comment: If the proxy is letting all the traffic, is it not doing any authentication?? Also please post code snippets of your code changes.

Comment: The authentication code is in the challenge handler code, which is not getting kicked in. With the reverse proxy in between the app and MFP server, the app was crashing for the above mentioned reason, and without the reverse proxy, it was throwing the error that "Missing challenge handler...". Just for perspective, the Datapower Cordova app works correctly in the same configuration. Just to let you know, the code flow does not come up to the point of displaying the login form in the app (in either use case).

Comment: I mean your server side authentication? What kind of authentication is your proxy doing? The sample was designed with a form-based challenge and LTPA, using DataPower LTPA features.

Comment: It is a form-based authentication at the reverse proxy.

Comment: You mention the handleChallenge never gets called right? What about canHandleResponse? Check your Wireshark trace as well. I'm interested to know if you see the form challenge coming in, and what HTTP status it comes with. And obviously make sure canHandleResponse checks for something that matches your form challenge.

Comment: Hi Nathan, the form challenge comes in with 200 from the reverse proxy and canHandleResponse() does check for the correct string in the form and is sending back true. Please see EDIT 3. After the EDIT 3, the app is going in an infinite loop and reverse proxy keeps sending auth form back.

Comment: You mentioned that the app does what it needs to do with the MFP server. Your gateway does not throw a form challenge when the app tries to get an auth token request to MFP?

Comment: After you clarify this point, come find me on our slack channel (https://ibm.biz/Bdr9AG) I'm very interested in understanding your complete flow.

Comment: Hi Nathan. Thanks for the invite. Please see EDIT 4. Your query made me rethink and redo my gateway configuration. The result for Android app changed a little but the app still crashed. I will be on the slack channel and will try to ping you, once you are online. Thanks.

Comment: Ok looks Like we are back to the original error. It is complaining that you have more than one WWW-Authenticate header. The MFP server sends one. Is it possible your gateway also has its own WWW-Authenticate header?

Comment: Hi Nathan, yes it looks like there are 2 WWW-Authenticate header in the "403 Forbidden" message from MFP server. Bearer Error="Insufficient Scope" and other one scope="accessRestricted". The server resource (Resource Adapter-> Balance) is behind the security check "accessRestricted", which is what I have used to bind to LtpaBasedSSO with the app. Please see EDIT 5.

Comment: Just tested the behavior with DataPower Cordova app. It does receive 2 WWW-Authenticate header, exactly like the one above and the app goes on to request a preauthorize to MFP and continues without problems.

Comment: Can you please post how you solved it? I am facing the similar issue, and the accepeted answer doesn't shed much light.

Comment: Please check the traces on wireshark or similar utility and see if you can see 2 WWW-Authenticate headers or only 1. What is your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MobileFirst server sends only 1 header with the same `WWW-Authenticate`.

The MobileFirst Android SDK only know how to handle a single `WWW-Authenticate` header.

I suspect that your gateway is breaking the value into multiple headers. Ideally, you should fix your gateway to prevent this behavior.

If not possible, open a support request to ask if the MFP SDK can be modified to accept such header broken in 2.